# Correct way to use Tukey's post hoc test for 2-way anova

Tags: anova, interaction, tukey-hsd-test

I did 2-way ANOVA on my microarray data where I have treated and controlled samples from two different tissues (total 8 arrays).

```
   sample1  control    tissue1
   sample2  treatment  tissue1
   sample3  control    tissue1
   sample4  treatment  tissue1
   sample5  control    tissue2
   sample6  treatment  tissue2
   sample7  control    tissue2
   sample8 treatment   tissue2
```

I need to answer the following:

1. in both tissues total number of genes regulated by the treatment
2. in tissue 1 total number of genes regulated by the treatment
3. in tissue 2 total number of genes regulated by the treatment

I did a two-way ANOVA (Treatment+Tissue+Treatment*Tissue). I identified 200 genes with Treatment factor. This answers my question 1. Additionally, 70 genes were regulated by Treatment*Tissue.

To answer 2 and 3, I did a Tukey's test on 270 genes (200 Treatment + 70 Treatment*Tissue). I get 170 genes regulated by Tissue 1 and 80 genes regulated by Tissue 2. I use interaction term while doing Tukey's test and consider adjusted p-values from Treat:Tissue1-Control:Tissue1 and Treat:Tissue2-Control:Tissue2.

I am not sure if these results are correct. What I understand from ANOVA is 200 genes are affected by treatment only, irrespective of treatment*tissue interaction. So for each tissue I should get 200+ genes, right? Can someone please suggest me the correct way to use Tukey's test?